# javascript obj.nextSibling.disabled

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">





  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
        src="/HRMS/struts/dojo/struts_dojo.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
        src="/HRMS/struts/ajax/dojoRequire.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/HRMS/struts/xhtml/styles.css" type="text/css"/>

<script language="JavaScript" src="/HRMS/struts/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="/HRMS/struts/xhtml/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="/HRMS/struts/css_xhtml/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

 

<body style="margin:0px;">
  
  
  


<!-- body starts here -->

<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
 <td valign="top">
 
  <!-- welcome Message starts here -->
  
 
 
  <!-- PAGE TITLE starts here -->
   
       <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
           <td class="pagetitle"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tr>
               <td class="pagetitle">OT/UT ENTRY</td>
             </tr>
           </table></td>
         </tr>
       </table>   
   
  <!-- PAGE TITLE ends here -->
  
  <!-- TO display success and error messages -->
  <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing= "0" cellpadding="0">
       <tr>
       <td colspan="2" class="successmsg"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="errors"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- End of displaying success or error messages -->
 
  <!-- FORM starts here -->
  
    

<script>
var xmlHttp;// global instance of XMLHttpRequest
var counter = 0;


function hoursValidator(empNo,obj){
 var mode = document.getElementById("mode");
 var selMode = mode.options[mode.selectedIndex].value;
 var otUtDate = document.getElementById("attendanceDateStr").value;
 var hrs = obj.value;
 var resp;

 if(hrs === '0'){
  alert("Entered hours should be more than 0");
  obj.value="";
  return false;
 }
 if(hrs === '12'){
  var row = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
  var minutes = row.querySelectorAll("id='minutes'");
  alert(row);
 // alert(mimutes);
 //  var x = obj.nextSibling.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("minutes").disabled = true;
  }

 
}



</script>
<form id="loadEmployeeOTUTEntry" name="empSuspensionViewSearch" action="/HRMS/hr/loadEmployeeOTUTEntry.action" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="cutOff" value="21-OCT-2015 00:00:00" id="cutOff"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="lastRunOtut" value="10-NOV-2015 11:50:04" id="cutOff"/>
        
<fieldset class="fieldset">
                  
     <legend class="legendtitle">OT/UT - ENTRY</legend>
          <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing= "0" cellpadding="0">
           <tr>
     <td class="labelone2">Branch:<span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
     <td class="dataone1">
     
     <select name="hrOtUtRegisterDtl.branchCode" id="branch" class="txtbox_mandatory">
    <option value="3102" selected="selected">AL AIN MALL ALAIN</option>


</select>
</td>
     
     <td class="labelone2">Department:<span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
     <td class="dataone1" colspan=2>
     
     <select name="hrOtUtRegisterDtl.deptCode" id="dept" class="txtbox_mandatory">
    <option value="16" selected="selected">CASH EXPRESS</option>


</select>
</td>
    </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td class="labelone1" width="15%">Date:<span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
                <td class="dataone2" width="35%"><input type="text" name="hrOtUtRegisterDtl.attendanceDateStr" value="12-Nov-2015" id="attendanceDateStr" class="txtbox" onblur="return dateValidator(id);"/>
</td>
                <td class="labelone2">Action:<span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
     <td class="dataone1" colspan = 2>
     
     <select name="hrOtUtRegisterDtl.otUtFormType" id="mode" class="txtbox_mandatory" onchange="getEmployees();">
    <option value="OT" selected="selected">OVER TIME</option>
    <option value="UT">UNDER TIME</option>


</select>
</td>
            </tr>  
           <tr>
             <td class="buttonband" colspan="4">
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Search" onclick="getEmployees();"/> &nbsp;
                <input name="button" type="reset" class="btn" value="Clear" onclick="reload();">
              </td>
            </tr>   
            <div
                   id="divSearchResult"         
    
             class="csShow"    
    
    >
    
    <script>document.getElementById("attendanceDateStr").readOnly = true;</script>
    <br><table>
    <tr>
      <td class="Htd_one1"  width="5%"><div align="center">Serial Number</div></td>
      <td class="Htd_one1" width="30%"><div align="center">Employee Number</div></td>
      <td class="Htd_one1" width="30%"><div align="center">Employee Name</div></td>
      <td class="Htd_one1" width="20%"><div align="center">Hours</div></td>
      <td class="Htd_one1" width="20%"><div align="center">Minutes</div></td>
      </tr>
         
           <tr class="oddrow">
           <td class="dataone2" align="center">
             <div align="center">1</div>
            </td>
            <td class="dataone2"><div align="center">
             11727</div>
             <input type="hidden" name="hrOtUtRegisterDtl.empNum" value="11727" id="empNum"/>
            </td>
            <td class="dataone2">
             OBAIDULLAH KHAN MOHAMMED YAQOOBULLAH KHAN MOHAMMED
             <input type="hidden" name="hrOtUtRegisterDtl.empName" value="OBAIDULLAH KHAN MOHAMMED YAQOOBULLAH KHAN MOHAMMED" id="empName"/>
            </td>
            <td class="dataone2" >
                <input type="text" name="hrOtUtRegisterDtl.hoursStr" value="" id="hours" class="txtbox_mandatory" onblur="hoursValidator('11727',this);" onkeydown="return allowNumberOnly(event);"/>

            </td>      
            <td class="dataone2" >
                <input type="text" name="hrOtUtRegisterDtl.minutesStr" value="" id="minutes" class="txtbox_mandatory" onblur="minsValidator('11727',this);" onkeydown="return allowNumberOnly(event);"/>

            </td>      
          </tr>
            
             <tr>
             <td class="buttonband" colspan="4">
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Submit" onclick="saveOTUT();"/> &nbsp;
              </td>
            </tr> 
</table> 
            
            </div>
           
        </table>
      </fieldset>
   
</form>




    
  <!-- FORM ends here -->
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<!-- body Ends here -->

   
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I have multiple rows which displays hours and minutes. If in one row user enters hours as 12, minutes should be disabled for that row.

```
//obj.nextSibling.disabled = true; 
//obj.nextSibling.readonly = true;
```

not working. Is ther any other syntax to achieve it?

```
<script>
function hoursValidator(empNo,obj){
    var hrs = obj.value;

    if(hrs === '12'){
        obj.nextSibling.disabled = true;
        obj.nextSibling.readOnly = true;
        document.getElementById("minutes").disabled = true;
        }
</script>

 <s:iterator status="stat" value="empList" id="empList">
       <tr>
       <td >
        <s:property value="empName" />
       </td>
       <td>
       <s:textfield name="hoursStr" value = "%{hoursStr}" onblur="hoursValidator('%{empNum}',this);" onkeydown="return allowNumberOnly(event);"  id="hours"/>
       </td>      
      <td class="dataone2" >
      <s:textfield name="minutesStr" value = "%{minutesStr}" onblur="minsValidator('%{empNum}',this);" id="minutes" onkeydown="return allowNumberOnly(event);"/>         </td>      
                  </tr>
        </iterator>
```

Comment: are you sure the if condition is working? I mean the if block is executing? Try a console inside if block and let me know

Comment: had set an alert.. so i know it was atleast getting inside the condition check.. BTW, readonly and disabled both are correct?

Comment: You can use either. But they are little different by the way they works. Remember `readOnly` should be in CamelCase to work in Firefox

Comment: `.nextSibling` could very well be a text node and not the desired element.  In many browsers, the newline and spaces you have between tags will be a text node.

Comment: oh.ok. any other way to achieve this?

Comment: When you call `hoursValidator()`, what element is `obj` that is passed to it?  We need to understand what is being passed in and what element in your HTML you want to disable based on the one that was passed in.

Comment: `obj.nextSibling` is null. What do you want exactly? Do you want to disable the `minutes` field?

Comment: Also, please post the generated HTML, not your template.  The Javascript must operate on the actual generated HTML so that's what we need to see.

Comment: as alert - [obj.nextSibling] - i get [OBJECT]. Here OBJ is that instant object of id "hours"

Comment: Try `nextElementSibling` instead of `nextSibling`.

Comment: @Oriol - the target object is in the next table cell.  You can't get there directly without going up the hierarchy first.

Comment: @jfriend00 I meant that `nextElementSibling` might be useful because it skips text nodes. Yes, probably additional things are needed, but I can't know without generated HTML.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to make sure that `obj` in your `hoursValidator()` function is actually the `hoursStr` object.  Some things you are reporting suggest that `obj` is not set correctly.

If `obj` is the `hoursStr` object, then you can get to the `minutesStr` object in the same row like this:

```
var row = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
var minutes = row.querySelectorAll("[name='hrOtUtRegisterDtl.minutesStr']");
minutes[0].disabled = true;
minutes[0].readonly = true;
```

You can't use `nextSibling` because the target object is in a different table cell - it's not a sibling in the same cell.

I see that you are using `id="minutes"` and `id="hours"` in each row.  Ids must be unique in the entire document so that will not work for a structure that is repeated in each row.  That's why I did not use those id values in my recommeded code above.

Working demo using your HTML here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/x3djcmf9/

---

And, if you only ever have one row with `id="minutes"`, then you can also do this:

```
var minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
minutes.disabled = true;
minutes.readonly = true;
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6dLgkm5v/

P.S. You probably want to re-enable the field if the number is edited to something other than "12".

Comment: row.querySelectorAll("[name='minutesStr']");  throws error - object doesnt support property..

Comment: i tried row.querySelectorAll("[id='minutes']") as well.. but same error

Comment: @user2093576 - Then please show your ACTUAL generated HTML, not your template.  We need to see the real HTML so we can see how to navigate it properly.  FYI, `.querySelectorAll()` is a method that exists on all elements in the document assuming this is a browser.  See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) if you want more info on it.

Comment: @user2093576 - the only other thing I can think of is that `obj` in your function is not what you think it is.  I'd suggest you do `console.log(obj)` in your function, then look in the debug log after running your function and see what it is.  I personally hate these event handlers in the HTML as it gets confusing how to properly pass arguments to them.  Much prefer unobstrusive Javavscript where you install event handlers in JS, not in HTML.

Comment: just added the picture of html.. nothing fancy there though. Just as I set a value for hours textfield and move to next field. onblur() calls hours validator.. which will check if hours is 12 then minutes to be disabled for that row

Comment: @user2093576 - We don't want a picture of your HTML.  We want to see the ACTUAL HTML.  That's what the Javascript operates on.  That's what you have to know to code.  You can get it from View/Source in the browser. My guess is that the main issue is that `obj` is not what you thought it was.  See the very first line of my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94893/discussion-between-user2093576-and-jfriend00).

Comment: @user2093576 - the code I suggested works using your HTML here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/x3djcmf9/.  The only change I made was to insert my recommended code and to define the function `allowNumberOnly` which wasn't defined in the code you posted.

Comment: The same code in struts2 as <s:textfield> isnt working. its working in the fiddle example

Comment: @user2093576 - I'm sorry, but we can only debug what we can see or try ourselves.  You will have to do some debugging to either figure out what is different in your struts code or to find some more info you can share with us about what might be different or what is not working properly.  I've made the code work with two different methods in the HTML you gave me.

Comment: ok.. got it.. its working for chrome but not in IE. I need to get it work for ie as well

Comment: it is IE7, cant see console in IE7

Comment: @user2093576 - There's no `querySelectorAll()` in IE7 (very ancient browser).  You would have to select a different way of finding the desired element that works in such an ancient browser.  One might ask why in the world you're attempting to support IE7?  It does not have enough market share any more to justifying writing and testing code for it.

Comment: cant help bro, client requirement

Comment: var row = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
  var rowIndex = row.rowIndex;
  alert(document.getElementById('minutes')[rowIndex]);
  document.getElementById("minutes")[rowIndex].disabled = true; Can i get the minutes with rowindex disabled?